# mysql utf-8 returns gibberish from one machine

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, utf-8

I have mysql DB with UTF-8 and application written in java with hibernate. When I run the application in eclipse everything is fine. But in production which is on a different machine the values returned from DB are corrupted.
I print the values to log (immediately after getting them) and I clearly see that the values I get from DB are corrupted in production.

The DB itself is the same DB for both environments. The values are stored fine.

Any ideas what can be the reason for this?

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to say that it happens sometimes. I think that in 50% of the times it works fine.

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://myDB:3306/myApp?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property> -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>


     <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider</property>
     <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">5</property>
     <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">10</property>
     <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">30000</property>

     <mapping class="someclass1"/>          
     <mapping class="someclass2"/>          
     <mapping class="someclass3"/>          
     <mapping class="someclass4"/>              

   </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: "I print the values to log (immediately after getting them) and I clearly see that the values I get from DB are corrupted in production." - Well, that could be an issue with how you're logging. It's very hard to tell what's wrong without *at least* seeing the code, and ideally the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**Reference URL:** https://docs.jboss.org/exojcr/1.12.13-GA/developer/en-US/html/ch-db-configuration-hibernate.html

Please verify the datasource configuration in your production environment whether the attributes - useUniCode and characterEncoding are set properly.
   **Example:**

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exodb?relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>
```

Comment: My hibernate.cfg.xml is located in one of my jars, I guess it is being used. Please see its content above in my original question.

Comment: I also printed the connection utl in the code and I see that it's as appears in the hibernate.cfg.xml